# FontIcon not display in AppBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try use the navbar in react. When use iconElementLeft for show icon in navbar it does not appear.

[image]

**My code:**

```
var React  = require('react'),
mui        = require('material-ui'),
Paper      = mui.Paper,
IconButton = mui.IconButton,
FontIcon   = mui.FontIcon,
AppBar     = mui.AppBar;

require('./style');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var menuButton = 
            <IconButton onClick={this.props.onMenuIconButtonTouch}>
                <FontIcon className='menu-icon icon-navigation-white icon-navigation-white-ic_menu_white_24dp' />
            </IconButton>;

        return 
            <Paper className='topNav' rounded={false}>
                <AppBar
                iconElementLeft={menuButton}
                title='Sample project'
                zDepth={0} />
            </Paper>;
    }
});
```

**Get two warning in console:**

> Warning: require('react/addons') is deprecated. Access using
>   require('react-addons-{addon}') instead.warning @
>   warning.js:45(anonymous function) @ addons.js:4(anonymous function) @
>   main.js:3038__webpack_require__ @ main.js:521fn @ main.js:76(anonymous
>   function) @ style-propable.js:3(anonymous function) @
>   main.js:3029__webpack_require__ @ main.js:521fn @ main.js:76(anonymous
>   function) @ app-bar.js:4(anonymous function) @
>   app-bar.js:184(anonymous function) @ main.js:3020__webpack_require__ @
>   main.js:521fn @ main.js:76(anonymous function) @ index.js:4(anonymous
>   function) @ main.js:3011__webpack_require__ @ main.js:521fn @
>   main.js:76(anonymous function) @ index.jsx:7(anonymous function) @
>   index.jsx:52(anonymous function) @ index.jsx:53(anonymous function) @
>   main.js:3002__webpack_require__ @ main.js:521fn @ main.js:76(anonymous
>   function) @ routes.jsx:18(anonymous function) @
>   routes.jsx:23(anonymous function) @ routes.jsx:24(anonymous function)
>   @ main.js:2993__webpack_require__ @ main.js:521fn @
>   main.js:76(anonymous function) @ app.jsx:8(anonymous function) @
>   app.jsx:20(anonymous function) @ app.jsx:21(anonymous function) @
>   main.js:1103__webpack_require__ @ main.js:521fn @ main.js:76(anonymous
>   function) @ multi_main:3(anonymous function) @
>   main.js:554__webpack_require__ @ main.js:521(anonymous function) @
>   main.js:544(anonymous function) @ main.js:547
>
> warning.js:45 Warning: React.findDOMNode is deprecated. Please use
>   ReactDOM.findDOMNode from require('react-dom') instead.

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-material-webpack-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack-dev-server.config.js --progress --colors --port 2992 --inline",
    "hot-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack-hot-dev-server.config.js --hot --progress --colors --port 2992 --inline",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack-production.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "start-dev": "node lib/server-development",
    "start": "node lib/server-production"
  },
  "precommit": [
    "lint"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "react",
    "starter",
    "boilerplate",
    "hot"
  ],
  "author": "Mike Lerner",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.3.0",
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^5.1.9",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.15.1",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "less": "^2.5.0",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.9.2",
    "material-ui-sass": "^0.7.2",
    "node-sass": "^3.2.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-fontawesome": "^0.3.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.5",
    "react-material-icon": "^0.1.0",
    "react-proxy-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "react-router": "^0.13.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.1.6",
    "sass-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "style-loader": "0.12.3",
    "superagent": "^1.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.8.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint": "^0.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I updated my question. Two warning are displayed

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it appears that `<FontIcon>` cannot be an empty tag.

Change your `FontIcon`:

```
<FontIcon className="material-icons">navigation</FontIcon>
```

I created an [app](https://github.com/brianswisher/material-ui-study/blob/master/bundle/javascripts/app/component/Material.jsx#L26) and [staged](https://material-ui-study.herokuapp.com/) it to investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

I using now this: https://github.com/andreypopp/react-fa

Its simple and working fine!

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Icon from 'react-fa'

ReactDOM.renderComponent(
  <Icon spin name="spinner" />,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

[image]